# How Wed Aug 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 date is come like in java 2016-08-09T18:30:00.000Z

Tags: java, html, date

i am selecting date from html calendar ,i am printing the selected date in java script using console.log(selecteddate),it is coming like this **Wed Aug 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530**, the same selecteddate i am sending to java and there i am printing the date with system.out.println(selecteddate) but the date is coming like this **2016-08-09T18:30:00.000Z**. the selected date is coming previous date.
how it is happening.any one please tell me. 
ex:if i select 2016-08-10 but it is coming like 2016-08-09 in java

Answer (score 1):

It is the same time.

18:30 plus 5.5 hours is 24:00 or 00:00 the next day.

This happens because of different time-zones.